# Creating an OCAML function to output a code file?

Tags: ocaml, ml

I'm looking to create a function to output a code file (looking to output a C++ file if possible) with OCAML.

Is there a way to easily do this or is using the `open_out` function with providing the code to write to the output file the only way possible to do this?

Thanks

Comment: What do you find difficult about opening a file and writing the code to it?

Comment: I was wondering if there is an in-built library which makes it easier to do so

Comment: SO isn't a good place to ask for library recommendations. See the [help/on-topic]. Specifically this: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._

Comment: @NiallMitch14 Still, what's difficult about `let o = open_out "code.cpp" in fprintf o "int main() {}"; close_out o;`?
`

Comment: @molbdnilo Nothing... I was looking to see if there was a better alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use `Out_channel` from `Core`

https://dev.realworldocaml.org/imperative-programming.html